# Django: __init__.py package breaks migrations

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-packages

In my app, I have file structure:

```
myapp/
    ...
    models.py
    helpers/
        __init__.py
        RandomFileName.py
    ...
```

In RandomFileName.py I have helper class that generates random file names for my models:

```
class RandomFileName(object):
    ...
```

In models I want to treat `helpers/` directory as a module:

```
from myapp.helpers import RandomFileName

class MyImage(models.Model):
    ...
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=RandomFileName('images/'))
    ...
```

Then, I run `python3 manage.py makemigrations myapp`
Looks good.

Then, I run `python3 manage.py migrate` and get an error:

```
in Migration
  ('image', models.ImageField(upload_to=myapp.helpers.RandomFileName.RandomFileName('images/'))),
AttributeError: type object 'RandomFileName' has no attribute 'RandomFileName'
```

Why is the RandomFileName doubled in migrations? Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow your **init**.py file could have imported your object. Check. If not, then simply doing myapp.helpers.RandomFileName('images/') instead (based on the exception message) will fix the issue.